# Defining routes and creating laravel Blade.php templates

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

So I am trying to create some blade templates using Laravel 6. I have a number of blade templates set up and working correctly but for the some reason, I am faced with an error 404 anytime I try to access the settings pages by link or by URL.

My directory is set up such that

```
- projectName
-- app
--- Http
---- Controllers
----- Controller.php
----- HouseController.php
-- resources
--- views
---- pages
----- emergencySettings.blade.php
----- personalSettings.blade.php
----- roommatesSettings.blade.php
----- informationSettings.blade.php
----- socialsSettings.blade.php
----- many other blade.php files which all work correctly
---- welcome.blade.php
-- routes
--- web.php
```

I have set up the routes in the web.php file like so

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

use App\Http\Controllers\HouseController;

Route::get('/pages/emergencySettings', [HouseController::class, 'emergencySettings']);
Route::get('/pages/personalSettings', [HouseController::class, 'personalSettings']);
Route::get('/pages/roommatesSettings', [HouseController::class, 'roommatesSettings']);
Route::get('/pages/socialsSettings', [HouseController::class, 'socialsSettings']);
Route::get('/pages/informationSettings', [HouseController::class, 'informationSettings']);
```

The controller is set up as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

The HouseController extends Controller and is set up as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\House;

class HouseController extends Controller
{
    public function emergencySettings(){
        return view('pages.emergencySettings');
    }
    public function informationSettings(){
        return view('pages.informationSettings');
    }
    public function personalSettings(){
        return view('pages.personalSettings');
    }
    public function roommatesSettings(){
        return view('pages.roommatesSettings');
    }
    public function socialsSettings(){
        return view('pages.socialsSettings');
    }
}
```

I would like to reiterate that this already includes many other blade templates, all included in web and controller in this exact format and working perfectly, but the settings pages always seem to return an error 404 and I cannot figure out what is preventing them from being correctly implemented into the framework.
Please help and thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you cache your routes for some reason? run `php artisan route:clear` to make sure they aren't cached

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: what URL are you trying to access? is this a webserver 404 or a Laravel 404 page?

Comment: This is within the PHP development server, which is accessed with 'php artisan serve'

Comment: what URL are you trying to access when you get the 404 error?

Comment: If I attempt http://127.0.0.1:8000/emergencySettings (for example), I get an error 404

Comment: that isn't the path for the route you defined above, you defined the path as `pages/emergencySettings`, so you should get a 404 for any path that doesn't match a route you have defined

Comment: I understand. So I am currently attempting to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/emergencySettings but I still receive an error claiming settings.blade.php does not exist

Comment: that view doesn't exist that is why ... your view is `pages.emergencySettings`, you created a folder named `pages` in the `views` folder and in there is your view, so that is the view name  (your controller above is returning that view) ... nothing you have provided is looking for a view named `settings`

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are saying. So why is it returning an error about a settings.blade file when I try to access that URL? https://ibb.co/4m7JDvd

Comment: does `emergencySettings` extend another template or include one? use the stacktrace to find what is trying to load a view named `settings`; the top of that page is cut off as well

Comment: can u show emergencySettings  page code also?